# Under what conditions $g(X_n,Y_n)\overset{d}{\rightarrow}g(X,Y)$?

Tags: probability, statistics

Under what conditions, given $X_n\overset{d}{\rightarrow}X$ and $Y_n\overset{d}{\rightarrow}Y$ $\Rightarrow$ $g(X_n,Y_n)\overset{d}{\rightarrow}g(X,Y)$

I know that we can't apply the continuous mapping theorem because $X_n\overset{d}{\rightarrow}X$ and $Y_n\overset{d}{\rightarrow}Y$ does not imply $(X_n,Y_n)\overset{d}{\rightarrow}(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 1):

The continuous mapping theorem applies to metric spaces and $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Euclidean metric is surely a metric space.

Comment: You are right, I have edited the question. It should make sense now.